# Listar objeto JSON en nodejs a traves de la API nasa

Tags: nodejs, api, express, fetch

Hola comunidad soy nuevo en nodejs y express, quisiera mostrar un objeto json de una imagen de la API nasa pero no se como mostrar solo 3 campos especificos del objeto
url,tittlee,explanation.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const API_KEY = "";


//routes
app.get("/fetch", async (req,res) =>{
console.log("images");
const url = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
const options = {
    "method" : "GET"
}

const response = await fetch(url,options)
.then(res => res.json())
.catch(e => {
    console.error({
        "message":"error",
        error: e
    })
})

console.log("RESPONSE:", response);
res.json(response);
```

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log("server listening o port",port));

Me pueden indicar como debo de realizarlo.
Muchas gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, remueve la key de tu pregunta. Eso es privado

Answer (score 2):

Sustituye la ultima línea `res.json(response);` por esto:

```
let { title, explanation, url } = response;
res.json({ title, explanation, url });
```

Esto extrae los campos `title`, `explanation` y  `url` del objeto response en variables del mismo nombre en la primera línea. Esto se conoce como desestructuración (Documentacion [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)).
Luego construyes una respuesta solo con los campos que necesitas.